# load php extensions in apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I think i am almost through setting up php and mysql together with apache on my debian server but it looks like the mysql extensions are not loaded when I serve pages

I only have basic understanding of apache conf files so I am probably missing something. All packages (debian, php5-mysql, mysql-server etc.) are up to date, so I suspect the issue comes from the way apache loads the php module.

Trying to run the serve this page (on Firefox client) confirms that all my extensions (especially mysql) are not loaded:

```
<?php
echo(phpversion());
?>


<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

> 5.4.44-0+deb7u1
>
> Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre [6] => zlib [7] => bcmath [8] => bz2 [9] => calendar [10] => ctype [11] => dba [12] => dom [13] => hash [14] => fileinfo [15] => filter [16] => ftp [17] => gettext [18] => SPL [19] => iconv [20] => json [21] => mbstring [22] => session [23] => posix [24] => Reflection [25] => standard [26] => shmop [27] => SimpleXML [28] => soap [29] => sockets [30] => Phar [31] => exif [32] => sysvmsg [33] => sysvsem [34] => sysvshm [35] => tokenizer [36] => wddx [37] => xml [38] => xmlreader [39] => xmlwriter [40] => zip [41] => apache2handler [42] => mhash )

Where as running with php form terminal yields what I would like:

```
 $ php test.php
```

> 5.6.13
>
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Core
>       [1] => date
>       [2] => ereg
>       [3] => libxml
>       [4] => pcre
>       [5] => sqlite3
>       [6] => ctype
>       [7] => dom
>       [8] => fileinfo
>       [9] => filter
>       [10] => hash
>       [11] => iconv
>       [12] => json
>       [13] => SPL
>       [14] => session
>       [15] => standard
>       [16] => mysqlnd
>       [17] => PDO
>       [18] => pdo_mysql
>       [19] => pdo_sqlite
>       [20] => Phar
>       [21] => posix
>       [22] => Reflection
>       [23] => mysqli
>       [24] => SimpleXML
>       [25] => mysql
>       [26] => tokenizer
>       [27] => xml
>       [28] => xmlreader
>       [29] => xmlwriter
>   )

```
 $ php5 test.php
```

> 5.4.44-0+deb7u1
>
> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Core
>       [1] => date
>       [2] => ereg
>       [3] => libxml
>       [4] => openssl
>       [5] => pcre
>       [6] => zlib
>       [7] => bcmath
>       [8] => bz2
>       [9] => calendar
>       [10] => ctype
>       [11] => dba
>       [12] => dom
>       [13] => hash
>       [14] => fileinfo
>       [15] => filter
>       [16] => ftp
>       [17] => gettext
>       [18] => SPL
>       [19] => iconv
>       [20] => json
>       [21] => mbstring
>       [22] => pcntl
>       [23] => session
>       [24] => posix
>       [25] => Reflection
>       [26] => standard
>       [27] => shmop
>       [28] => SimpleXML
>       [29] => soap
>       [30] => sockets
>       [31] => Phar
>       [32] => exif
>       [33] => sysvmsg
>       [34] => sysvsem
>       [35] => sysvshm
>       [36] => tokenizer
>       [37] => wddx
>       [38] => xml
>       [39] => xmlreader
>       [40] => xmlwriter
>       [41] => zip
>       [42] => PDO
>       [43] => gd
>       [44] => intl
>       [45] => mcrypt
>       [46] => mysql
>       [47] => mysqli
>       [48] => pdo_mysql
>       [49] => mhash
>   )

Any help is welcomed, also I am quite new around here so if more information is needed just let me know!

---

my configuration:

```
$ sudo more /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 7.8

Linux **** 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:35:27 CET 2015   x86_64
U/Linux



$ php5 -v
PHP 5.4.44-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2015 09:51:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies



$ php -v
PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2015 04:46:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies`


$ apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 18 2015 09:51:24
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     ITK
  threaded:     no
  forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/experimental/itk"
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"


$ more /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
# Deny access to raw php sources by default
# To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
# only in specific virtual host or directory
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

$ more /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

---

```
$ php -i |grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, 
CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator,
FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException,
LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, 
ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, 
RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException,
SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue,
SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
```

Comment: Try loading `php5-mysqlnd` instead of `php5-mysql`

Comment: I don't think your problem is with extensions but instead you have two different installs of PHP and Apache references the *old* one.

Comment: @ Machavity and @JasonMcCreary:  thanks for your input guys. I have actually tried with both`php5-mysqlnd` and `php5-mysql` but this does not help. Also how come, even with php5.4 I dnt get the same outcome in terminal and apache?

Comment: Show us what the output of `php -i | grep ini` is, I'd say you've got a bunch of ini files, and not all versions are using the same ini files (which is fine, but you have to enable the extensions in the correct ini files)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: Thanks. Please see the edit in the question. the php.ini file retrieved from apache with phpinfo() is /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  though.

Comment: Voted to close.  This really belongs on ServerFault as it's a software setup issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: @Crontab: sorry this is actually my first post. I reposted on server fault as per your advice.  http://serverfault.com/questions/721772/load-php-extensions-in-apache

Comment: @Xavier No worries, hopefully you'll have better luck over there with this problem!